# Verb phrase may be coming

Tags: modal-verbs

In this sentence below:

> *“They **may be coming** sooner than we expected”*.

Is the word ‘be’ in this sentence a helping verb?
Is the word ‘coming’ in this sentence a verbal?
What tense is this sentence in?

I think it’s in progressive tense but it doesn’t match up with how any of the progressive tenses are formed so I’m a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

The verb phrase in this sentence is "may be coming"

English verbs can be formed as "modal verb + infinitive"

> He *may play* tennis.

The infinitive can be a progressive "be playing" or perfect "have played" form

> He *may be playing* tennis.

The meaning of the progressive form is surprising:  "He may play tennis" is a statement giving permission.  "He is allowed to play tennis".  But the continuous form "He may be playing tennis" states a possibility "It is possible that he is playing tennis."

In your sentence, the tense is sort of irrelevant because it's a modal verb "may" (it's the present tense, but modal verbs don't always have past tenses).  The "verbal" is the phrase "may be coming". And it expresses possibility:

> It is possible that they are coming sooner than expected.

Comment: I feel confused by the answer.thought

Comment: I thought an infinitive was  to + base verb or an split infinitive. Are you saying that the word “be” in the sentence I wrote is an infinitive?

Comment: Is there a site where I could learn more about those things?

Comment: "be" is a bare infinitive.  Modal expressions usually use modal verb+bare infinitive.  Loads of sites, at different levels. Search for "modal verbs".  British Council, for example https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/modal-verbs

Answer (score 1):

As well as what James K has said, another way to think about it is that you're taking a simple statement of **fact**:

*They **are** coming sooner than expected*

and using *may* to talk about the **chance** this might happen instead:

*They **may be** coming sooner than expected*

As James said, *may* is followed by the infinitive, so *are* becomes *be*. The rest of the sentence stays the same, because really all you're doing is changing the verb phrase so it sounds less like a sure thing, and more like something that's *possible*.

You could say *may come* instead, but that's the *may* form equivalent to *will come*. *They may be coming* is equivalent to *they are coming*. Both express the future, but in subtly different ways, and the *may* forms reflect those meanings (just with an element of "there's a chance" added!)